# How to set an IOTA node for the Data Markeplace?

Tags: data-marketplace

I'd like to set up an IOTA node and put the data on the Data Marketplace but it'seems that the API are not published yet.
Does anyone know when will be available?

Comment: Hi, questions about guessing future releases are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. To emphasize that I closed the question.